# Changing text value for each list item in flutter

Tags: datetime, listview, flutter, button, text

I have a list of buttons. onPressed function triggers datePicker function, after choosing date, button's text should change to the picked date. Each date is saved to a list of DateTime values, 'dates', which I use later. Dates list and the listView are dynamic, their length depends on the number chosen by user.  I've initiallized buttonText and set its value in initState to 'date'. The problem is, after picking date, each button displays the same date.

```
Future<DateTime> _pickDate() async {
    DateTime chosen = DateTime.now();
    DateTime date = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: pickedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 100),
        lastDate: DateTime.now());
    if (date != null) {
      setState(() {
        chosen = date;
        print(chosen);
        dates.add(chosen);
        print(dates);
      });
    }
    return chosen;
  }
```

```
Widget _dateList() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          //border: Border.all(
          //  color: Colors.red
          // )
          ),
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount:
              pregController.text == '' ? 0 : int.parse(pregController.text),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            DateTime birth = DateTime.now();
            return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
              child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors
                      .primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
                  key: Key(index.toString()),
                  child: Text(
                    buttonText,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    )),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    birth = await _pickDate();
                    setState(() {
                      buttonText =
                          '${dates[index].day}/${dates[index].month}/${dates[index].year}';
                    });
                  }),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
class Test1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => Test1State();

}

class Test1State extends State<Test1> {
  List<DateTime> dates = [
    DateTime.now(),
    DateTime.now(),
    DateTime.now(),
    DateTime.now(),
    DateTime.now(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    body: _dateList(),
  );

  Future<DateTime> _pickDate(DateTime initialDate) async {
    DateTime chosen = DateTime.now();
    DateTime date = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: initialDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 100),
        lastDate: DateTime.now());
    if (date != null) {
      setState(() {
        chosen = date;
        print(chosen);
        dates.add(chosen);
        print(dates);
      });
    }
    return chosen;
  }

  Widget _dateList() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        //border: Border.all(
        //  color: Colors.red
        // )
      ),
      child: ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: dates.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            DateTime birth = DateTime.now();
            return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
              child: RaisedButton(
                  color: Colors
                      .primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
                  key: Key(index.toString()),
                  child: Text(
                    '${dates[index].day}/${dates[index].month}/${dates[index].year}',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    birth = await _pickDate(birth);
                    setState(() {
                      dates[index] = birth;
                    });
                  }),
            );
          }),
    );
  }

}
```